# Call panel.invalidate outside form class in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to call "panel.invalidate" outside my form (WINform) class also I need to change some other controls as well, I read similar question here, and tried what they said, but it didn't work and I wasn't convinced at all.

The answer I read was about exposing a public method like this:

```
public void EnableButton(bool enable)
{
    this.myButton.Enabled = enable;
}
```

Also I made a static instance in the other file

```
 static Form1 myForm = new Form1();
```

Any useful suggestions??

Comment: The answer I talked about didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work how? Threw an exception? Compile-time error? Your computer created a black hole that swallowed your cat?

Comment: I meant by "Didn't work", nothing changed in the controls.Nothing was drawn on the panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the "myForm" reference.  It is a reference to an instance of Form1 that isn't visible and doesn't match the one that the user is looking at.  It can't be a match, you created a new one.

Whatever class needs to update the form must have a constructor that takes a Form1 reference.  You can create the class object in your Form1 constructor or Load event, pass "this".  Using Application.OpenForms[0] is another way to get the reference, one you should not use.

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating from the same thread? Otherwise you might need to use Invoke.
Here's a nice short article about how to do that:

http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Control.Invalidate()` is a public method, but the control itself is most likely not public. You will have to expose the call to `Control.Invalidate()` through a public facing method in your form or by marking the control in question as public.

```
public class MyForm : Form {
    private TextBox tbxName = new TextBox();

    public InvalidateTextBox() {
        tbxName.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class MyForm : Form {
    public TextBox tbxName = new TextBox();
}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    public void InvalidateTextBox(MyForm form) {
        form.tbxName.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: My function is already "Public", 

      public void panelInvalidation()
        {
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }
And this one also,

        public void listBoxAdd(object g)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(g);
        }